# SQL Server - Using SQL JOIN and UNION

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I have 2 successful SQL queries that I'm trying to combine into 1.  One query obtains the total cost of all products, and the other query obtains the total revenue from those products.  I would like to have a third query that sorts by profit (revenue - cost).

Query 1 sums up total cost (spend) by product id (id) from 3 similar tables using UNION ALL.

```
SELECT id, SUM(spend) as spend_total
                FROM (
                    SELECT id, spend 
                    FROM vendor_1 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT id, spend 
                    FROM vendor_2
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT id, spend 
                    FROM vendor_3
                ) as SpendTotal  
                GROUP BY id ORDER BY spend_total DESC
```

Query 2 sums up total revenue (rev) from 1 table

```
SELECT id, SUM(rev) as rev_total 
                FROM income
                GROUP BY id ORDER by rev_total DESC
```

Here is my failed attempt on joining the two and sorting it by (rev - spend)

```
SELECT income.id, total_rev - total_spend as result 
                FROM (SELECT id, SUM(rev) as total_rev
                        FROM income
                        GROUP BY id) as rev
                JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(spend) as total_spend
                    FROM (
                        SELECT id, spend 
                        FROM vendor_1 
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT id, spend 
                        FROM vendor_2
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT id, spend 
                        FROM vendor_3
                    ) as SpendTotal
                    GROUP BY id) as vendor_1 ON vendor_1.id = income.id order by result DESC
```

Comment: What's wrong with the result? Can you please show results and expected results?

Comment: What does "failed attempt" mean? Do you get an error? Do you not get the right results?

Comment: @SeanLange beat you do it ;)

Comment: @Eli and SeanLange - sorry I'm not sure how to get error messages.  I use this code in PHP and no results appear.  Nothing on the page appears after that line of SQL code, so I'm assuming there's an error.  Is there a way to read the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `SELECT` and `JOIN` you are using the `income.id` instead `rev.id`.

Can you try the query below:

```
SELECT id, result
FROM (
    SELECT rev.id, rev.total_rev - vendor_4.total_spend AS result
    FROM (
        SELECT id, SUM(rev) AS total_rev
        FROM income
        GROUP BY id
        ) AS rev
    JOIN (
        SELECT id, SUM(spend) AS total_spend
        FROM (
            SELECT id, spend
            FROM vendor_1

            UNION ALL

            SELECT id, spend
            FROM vendor_2

            UNION ALL

            SELECT id, spend
            FROM vendor_3
            ) AS SpendTotal
        GROUP BY id
        ) AS vendor_4 ON vendor_4.id = rev.id
    ) R
ORDER BY result DESC
```

Comment: Perfect!!  Thank you @Arulkumar much appreciated your quick response

Comment: By the way, what is the R for on the second to last line?

Comment: Just an alias name for the query block, it helped to use the `ORDER BY result`

Answer (score 1):

**You should to use one more sub query. try this -**

```
select T1.*,T2.*
FROM
(
SELECT id, SUM(spend) as spend_total
                FROM (
                    SELECT id, spend 
                    FROM vendor_1 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT id, spend 
                    FROM vendor_2
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT id, spend 
                    FROM vendor_3
                ) as SpendTotal  
                GROUP BY id
) as T1
JOIN
(    
                SELECT id, SUM(rev) as rev_total 
                FROM income
                GROUP BY id 
) as T2
ON T1.Id = T2.Id
```